# Existence of a sub-series that passes the ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a summable sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0, 1)$, is there a necessary condition for a subsequence $\{a_{k_i}\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\{a_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ to exist such that $\lim_i \dfrac{a_{k_{i+1}}}{a_{k_i}}$ exists? For instance, for any $r>1$, the sequence $\{n^{-rn}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $\{n^{-r}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, and has $\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \dfrac{(n+1)^{-r(n+1)}}{n^{-rn}} = 0$. The sequence $\{n^{-r}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (so far as I have known) is quite a typical example of a summable sequence that does not pass the ratio test, but still has a desired subsequence. I wonder if there is a necessary condition for the existence of such a subsequence.

Comment: I don't think that the set of ratios $\{\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}\}$ is necessarily bounded. Consider the sequence defined by $a_{2n} = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{n^3}$. I'm not entirely sure about the reasoning in your second paragraph, but it should indeed be possible to find a subsequence such that the ratios converge to $0$ for any summable sequence. You might wish to try to see why this holds yourself.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Yours is a very nice counter-example, and I suppose I do not need that condition.

Comment: @legionwhale Also, from your example, I should try to look for conditions for a summable sequence to have a subsequence $\{ a_{k_i} \}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\left\{ \dfrac{a_{k_{i+1}}}{a_{k_i}} \right\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. It would be also nice to ask, if such a subsequence exists, is there a different one that has its ratio converging to a different limit.

Comment: As I mention, for any summable sequence, it will be possible to find a subsequence with ratios converging to $0$, in which case the sequence of ratios *for the subsequence* is certainly bounded. My counterexample is only to show that the ratios are not necessarily bounded for the original sequence.